# How does Ember Inspector get the data from the app?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm looking into building a Chrome extension which can be used alongside with Ember Inspector and provide app specific information, settings for my own use cases.

I tried different ways of accessing the app instance, but with our build, it is not exposed globally, and I don't intend to do that. However, Ember Inspector can still see the app, controllers, routes etc. and I'm wondering how it does it. I've been looking into the source code of the inspector but no luck finding what I'm looking for. Does anyone have some insight maybe how it works? I'm using Ember 1.13.

Comment: The source code for the Inspector is publicly available: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector.

Comment: It seems ember inspector is an ember app itself, thus it reads the data throughout glimmer/ember-data adapter/model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more research I found the solution: There is an array `Ember.Namespace.NAMESPACES`, after checking which element is the instance of `Ember.Application` we can use that to access the application instance.